# My program won't count the number of lines words or characters propery?

Tags: c++, file, parsing, command-line-arguments

So I'm writing a program where multiple files are taken command line arguments.For an example I output program.exe file1.txt file2.txt on command prompt. For some reason my output is not showing the right results. When I enter two file names it only shows the first filename twice.I have attached a screenshot.It is also not counting the chars words or characters. I thought it had to do something with local or global variables but I have tried them to put all over the place.Or maybe I'm blind to my own mistakes.I will be grateful for any advice.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include  <fstream>

using namespace std;
int i;
char ch;
int charcounter=0;
int wordcounter=0;
int linecounter=0;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {
 for ( i = 1; i < argc; i++ ){

  if (argc<2){
    cout<<"you did not enter enough arguments"<<endl;
  }
    else {
        string filename;
        ifstream thefile;
        filename=argv[i];

        thefile.open(argv[i]);
        if (thefile.is_open() && thefile.good())
        {
                while (ch!= EOF){
                    charcounter++;

                    if (ch ==' ')
                    wordcounter++;
                   else if (ch =='\n')
                        linecounter++;

                ch=thefile.get();
                cout<<setw(12)<<"Lines"<<' '<<linecounter;
                cout<<' ';
                cout<<setw(12)<<"Words"<<' '<<wordcounter;
                cout<<' ';
                cout<<setw(12)<<"Characters"<<' '<<charcounter;
                cout<<' ';
                cout<<"filename"<<' '<<argv[i];
                thefile.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many problems here. First, you are using `ch` without initialising. Second, you are closing the file stream after reading the first character. You probably want to print statistics and file name after the `while (ch!= EOF){...}` block. Proper indentation will help to make things clearer.